# A reshape puzzle in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

Yet another reshape problem in `data.table`

```
set.seed(1234)
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c(1,2,3),each=4), y=c("A","B"), v=sample(1:100,12))
#    x y  v
# 1: 1 A 12
# 2: 1 B 62
...
#11: 3 A 63
#12: 3 B 49
```

I would like to do a cumulative sum of `x` and `v` by `y` but the result to be presented as:
The number of lines always stays the same, and when `y==A` the `SUM.*.A` is incremented, same when `y==B`. (As usual `y` could have many factors, 2 in this example)

```
#     SUM.x.A SUM.x.B  SUM.v.A SUM.v.B
# 1:        1      NA       12      NA
# 2:        1       1       12      62
...
#11:       12       9       318     289
#12:       12      12       318     338
```

EDIT: Here is my poor solution clearly overly complicated

```
#first step is to create cumsum columns
colNames <- c("x","v"); newColNames <- paste0("SUM.",colNames)
DT[, newColNames:=lapply(.SD,cumsum) ,by=y, .SDcols=colNames, with=F];
#now we need to reshape each SUM.* to SUM.*.{yvalue}
DT[,N:=.I]; setattr(DT,"sorted","N")

g <- function(DT,SD){
  cols <- c('N',grep('SUM',colnames(SD), value=T));
  Yval <- unique(SD[,y]);
  merge(DT, SD[,cols, with=F], suffixe=c('',paste0('.',Yval)), all.x=T);    
}

DT <- Reduce(f=g,init=DT,x=split(DT,DT$y));

locf = function(x) {
  ind = which(!is.na(x))    
  if(is.na(x[1])) ind = c(1,ind)
  rep(x[ind], times = diff( c(ind, length(x) + 1) )) 
}

newColNames <- grep('SUM',colnames(DT),value=T);
DT <- DT[, (newColNames):=lapply(.SD, locf), .SDcols=newColNames]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
cumsum0 <- function(x) { x <- cumsum(x); ifelse(x == 0, NA, x) }
DT2 <- DT[, {SUM.<-y; lapply(data.table(model.matrix(~ SUM.:x + SUM.:v + 0)), cumsum0)}]
setnames(DT2, sub("(.):(.)", "\\2.\\1", names(DT2)))
```

Simplifications:

1) If using `0` in place of `NA` is ok then it can be simplified by omitting the first line which defines `cumsum0` and replacing `cumsum0` in the next line with `cumsum`.

2) The result of the second line has these names:

```
> names(DT2)
[1] "SUM.A:x" "SUM.B:x" "SUM.A:v" "SUM.B:v"
```

so if that is sufficient the last line can be dropped since its only purpose is to make the names exactly the same as in the question.

The result (without the simplifications) is:

```
> DT2
    SUM.x.A SUM.x.B SUM.v.A SUM.v.B
 1:       1      NA      12      NA
 2:       1       1      12      62
 3:       2       1      72      62
 4:       2       2      72     123
 5:       4       2     155     123
 6:       4       4     155     220
 7:       6       4     156     220
 8:       6       6     156     242
 9:       9       6     255     242
10:       9       9     255     289
11:      12       9     318     289
12:      12      12     318     338
```

Comment: You could replace `SUM. <- y` with `SUM. <- factor(y)`  but actually in "R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)" I get no warnings.   What version are you using?

Comment: Note this in the News for 3.0.0 : *To support options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE), model.frame(), model.matrix() and replications() now automatically convert character vectors to factors without a warning.*

Comment: I think its pretty specific to this question. There are some reshaping solutions using `data.table` in SO (maybe posted by you?) but at this point I am not sure that reshaping is the best use of `data.table` without some further development.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I tried to wrap your stuff in a function and use `:=` instead of creating `DT2`, but then `DT` do not get updated. It looks like `DT` is getting modified in `lapply(data.table(model.matrix(~ SUM.:x + SUM.:v + 0)), cumsum0)` am I correct ?

Comment: Try `.Internal(inspect(DT)); DT0<-DT; DT2 <- DT[, {SUM.<-y; lapply(data.table(model.matrix(~ SUM.:x + SUM.:v + 0)), cumsum)}]; .Internal(inspect(DT)); identical(DT0,DT); identical(as.data.frame(DT0),as.data.frame(DT))` and I get the same addresses and `TRUE` for both comparisons so `DT` does not appear to be modified.

Comment: Yes, what I meant is I am trying to do `function(DT){DT[,(myNames):={SUM.<-y; lapply(data.table(model.matrix(~ SUM.:x + SUM.:v + 0)), cumsum)}];}` which work on this sample (`f(DT)` updates `DT`) but not on my real training set

Comment: If it works on the sample data then its unlikely anyone could respond without new sample data that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:

```
ys <- unique(DT$y)
sdcols <- c("x", "v")
cols <- paste0("SUM.", sdcols)
DT[, c(cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = y, .SDcols = sdcols]
for( i in seq_along(ys)) {
    cols <- paste0("SUM.", sdcols, ".", ys[i])
    DT[, c("v1", "v2") := list(SUM.x, SUM.v[i]), by = SUM.x]
    DT[, c("v1", "v2") := list(c(rep(NA_integer_, (i-1)), v1)[seq_len(.N)], 
    c(rep(NA_integer_, (i-1)), v2)[seq_len(.N)])]
    setnames(DT, c("v1", "v2"), cols)
}
```

---

My version of benchmarking with mnel's (from his post) and this function:

#### The function from this post:

```
arun <- function(DT) {

    ys <- unique(DT$y)
    sdcols <- c("x", "v")
    cols <- paste0("SUM.", sdcols)
    DT[, c(cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = y, .SDcols = sdcols]
    for( i in seq_along(ys)) {
        cols <- paste0("SUM.", sdcols, ".", ys[i])
        DT[, c("v1", "v2") := list(SUM.x, SUM.v[i]), by = SUM.x]
        DT[, c("v1", "v2") := list(c(rep(NA_integer_, (i-1)), v1)[seq_len(.N)], 
        c(rep(NA_integer_, (i-1)), v2)[seq_len(.N)])]
        setnames(DT, c("v1", "v2"), cols)
    }
    DT
}
```

#### Function from mnel's post:

```
mnel <- function(DT) {
    set.seed(1234)
    DT <- data.table(x=rep(c(1,2,3),each=4), y=c("A","B"), v=sample(1:100,12))
    DT[, id := seq_len(nrow(DT))]
    setkey(DT, y)
    uniqY <- unique(DT$y)
    for(jj in uniqY){
      nc <- do.call(paste, c(expand.grid('Sum', c('x','v'),jj), sep ='.'))
      DT[.(jj), (nc) := list(cumsum(x), cumsum(v))]

    }
    setkey(DT, id)
    DT[, 5:8 := lapply(.SD, function(x) { 
      xn <- is.na(x)
      x[xn] <- -Inf
      xx <- cummax(x)
      # deal with leading NA values
        if(xn[1]){
        xn1 <- which(xn)[1]
      xx[seq_len(xn1)] <- NA}   
      xx }), .SDcols = 5:8]
}
```

#### Function from statquant:

```
statquant <- function(DT){
    #first step is to create cumsum columns
    colNames <- c("x","v")
    DT[, paste0("SUM.",colNames):=lapply(.SD,cumsum) ,by=y, .SDcols=colNames];
    #now we need to reshape each SUM.* to SUM.*.{yvalue}
    DT[,N:=.I]; setattr(DT,"sorted","N")

    g <- function(DT,SD){
      cols <- c('N',grep('SUM',colnames(SD), value=T));
      Yval <- unique(SD[,y]);
      merge(DT, SD[,cols, with=F], suffix=c('',paste0('.',Yval)), all.x=T);    
    }

    DT <- Reduce(f=g,init=DT,x=split(DT,DT$y));

    locf = function(x) {
      ind = which(!is.na(x))    
      if(is.na(x[1])) ind = c(1,ind)
      rep(x[ind], times = diff( c(ind, length(x) + 1) )) 
    }

    newColNames <- grep('SUM',colnames(DT),value=T);
    DT <- DT[, (newColNames):=lapply(.SD, locf), .SDcols=newColNames]
    DT
}
```

#### Function from grothendieck

```
grothendieck <- function(DT) {
    cumsum0 <- function(x) { x <- cumsum(x); ifelse(x == 0, NA, x) }
    DT2 <- DT[, {SUM.<-y; lapply(data.table(model.matrix(~ SUM.:x + SUM.:v + 0)), cumsum0)}]
    setnames(DT2, sub("(.):(.)", "\\2.\\1", names(DT2)))
    DT2
}
```

#### Benchmarking:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
set.seed(1234)
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c(1,2,3),each=4), y=c("A","B"), v=sample(1:100,12))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( s <- statquant(copy(DT)), g <- grothendieck(copy(DT)), 
                m <- mnel(copy(DT)), a <- arun(copy(DT)), times = 1e3)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                         expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#     s <- statquant(copy(DT)) 13.041125 13.674083 14.493870 17.273151 144.74186  1000
#  g <- grothendieck(copy(DT))  3.634120  3.859143  4.006085  4.443388  80.01984  1000
#          m <- mnel(copy(DT))  7.819286  8.234178  8.596090 10.423668  87.07668  1000
#          a <- arun(copy(DT))  6.925419  7.369286  7.703003  9.262719  53.39823  1000
```

#### resulting data.table "a" (arun's)

```
#     x y  v SUM.x SUM.v SUM.x.A SUM.v.A SUM.x.B SUM.v.B
#  1: 1 A 12     1    12       1      12      NA      NA
#  2: 1 B 62     1    62       1      12       1      62
#  3: 1 A 60     2    72       2      72       1      62
#  4: 1 B 61     2   123       2      72       2     123
#  5: 2 A 83     4   155       4     155       2     123
#  6: 2 B 97     4   220       4     155       4     220
#  7: 2 A  1     6   156       6     156       4     220
#  8: 2 B 22     6   242       6     156       6     242
#  9: 3 A 99     9   255       9     255       6     242
# 10: 3 B 47     9   289       9     255       9     289
# 11: 3 A 63    12   318      12     318       9     289
# 12: 3 B 49    12   338      12     318      12     338
```

#### Resulting data.table "m" (mnel's)

```
#    x y  v id Sum.x.A Sum.v.A Sum.x.B Sum.v.B
#  1: 1 A 12  1       1      12      NA      NA
#  2: 1 B 62  2       1      12       1      62
#  3: 1 A 60  3       2      72       1      62
#  4: 1 B 61  4       2      72       2     123
#  5: 2 A 83  5       4     155       2     123
#  6: 2 B 97  6       4     155       4     220
#  7: 2 A  1  7       6     156       4     220
#  8: 2 B 22  8       6     156       6     242
#  9: 3 A 99  9       9     255       6     242
# 10: 3 B 47 10       9     255       9     289
# 11: 3 A 63 11      12     318       9     289
# 12: 3 B 49 12      12     318      12     338
```

#### Resulting data.table "s" (statquant's)

```
#      N x y  v SUM.x SUM.v SUM.x.A SUM.v.A SUM.x.B SUM.v.B
#  1:  1 1 A 12     1    12       1      12      NA      NA
#  2:  2 1 B 62     1    62       1      12       1      62
#  3:  3 1 A 60     2    72       2      72       1      62
#  4:  4 1 B 61     2   123       2      72       2     123
#  5:  5 2 A 83     4   155       4     155       2     123
#  6:  6 2 B 97     4   220       4     155       4     220
#  7:  7 2 A  1     6   156       6     156       4     220
#  8:  8 2 B 22     6   242       6     156       6     242
#  9:  9 3 A 99     9   255       9     255       6     242
# 10: 10 3 B 47     9   289       9     255       9     289
# 11: 11 3 A 63    12   318      12     318       9     289
# 12: 12 3 B 49    12   338      12     318      12     338
```

#### Resulting data.table "g" (grothendieck's)

```
#    SUM.x.A SUM.x.B SUM.v.A SUM.v.B
#  1:       1      NA      12      NA
#  2:       1       1      12      62
#  3:       2       1      72      62
#  4:       2       2      72     123
#  5:       4       2     155     123
#  6:       4       4     155     220
#  7:       6       4     156     220
#  8:       6       6     156     242
#  9:       9       6     255     242
# 10:       9       9     255     289
# 11:      12       9     318     289
# 12:      12      12     318     338
```

Comment: cumsum(.SD) is nifty syntax but creates at least three copies of the .SD object.

Comment: @mnel and Arun, I answered with a benchmark removing the NA-job and updating with mnel suggestion...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is the best solution, but you could do something like the following.

```
set.seed(1234)
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c(1,2,3),each=4), y=c("A","B"), v=sample(1:100,12))
DT[, id := seq_len(nrow(DT))]

setkey(DT, y)

uniqY <- unique(DT$y)

for(jj in uniqY){
  nc <- do.call(paste, c(expand.grid('Sum', c('x','v'),jj), sep ='.'))
  DT[.(jj), (nc) := list(cumsum(x), cumsum(v))]

}

setkey(DT, id)

DT[, 5:8 := lapply(.SD, function(x) { 
  xn <- is.na(x)
  x[xn] <- -Inf
  xx <- cummax(x)
  # deal with leading NA values
    if(xn[1]){
    xn1 <- which(xn)[1]
  xx[seq_len(xn1)] <- NA}   

  xx }), .SDcols = 5:8]
```

Comment: yes It is much better than mine, I always forget about `for` loops for that king of job, the `5:8` at the end is easily replacable. Also why do you not use na.locf ?

Comment: looking at the source code for na.locf it looks like it does a lot more work than you require ( not speed checked though), also not using means not having to load zoo

Comment: The for loop will not be required if [FR 2619](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2619&group_id=240&atid=978) is implemented.