# Recode categorical factor with N categories into N binary columns

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

**Original data frame:**

```
v1 = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE)
v2 = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE)
df = data.frame(v1,v2)
df
```

```
   v1 v2
1   b  c
2   a  a
3   c  c
4   b  a
5   c  c
6   c  b
7   a  a
8   a  b
9   a  c
10  a  b
```

**New data frame:**

```
new_df = data.frame(row.names=rownames(df))
for (i in colnames(df)) {
    for (x in letters[1:3]) {
        #new_df[x] = as.numeric(df[i] == x)
        new_df[paste0(i, "_", x)] = as.numeric(df[i] == x)
    }
}
```

```
   v1_a v1_b v1_c v2_a v2_b v2_c
1     0    1    0    0    0    1
2     1    0    0    1    0    0
3     0    0    1    0    0    1
4     0    1    0    1    0    0
5     0    0    1    0    0    1
6     0    0    1    0    1    0
7     1    0    0    1    0    0
8     1    0    0    0    1    0
9     1    0    0    0    0    1
10    1    0    0    0    1    0
```

For small datasets this is fine, but it becomes slow for much larger datasets.

Anyone know of a way to do this without using looping?

Comment: Your first data frame had two variables, but it looks like you only converted the second one. Can you clarify that a bit?

Comment: you're overwriting your data. It should have 6 columns in output.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part -- I fixed it in the code above. There should be three new columns for each original column in the above example. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @Keith, have you checked the answers that've been posted?

Comment: @Arun done. there were many helpful solution. I appreciate everyone's input!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Even better with the help of @AnandaMahto's search capabilities,

```
model.matrix(~ . + 0, data=df, contrasts.arg = lapply(df, contrasts, contrasts=FALSE))
#    v1a v1b v1c v2a v2b v2c
# 1    0   1   0   0   0   1
# 2    1   0   0   1   0   0
# 3    0   0   1   0   0   1
# 4    0   1   0   1   0   0
# 5    0   0   1   0   0   1
# 6    0   0   1   0   1   0
# 7    1   0   0   1   0   0
# 8    1   0   0   0   1   0
# 9    1   0   0   0   0   1
# 10   1   0   0   0   1   0
```

---

I think this is what you're looking for. I'd be happy to delete if it's not so. Thanks to @G.Grothendieck (once again) for the [**excellent usage**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16192335/559784) of `model.matrix`!

```
cbind(with(df, model.matrix(~ v1 + 0)), with(df, model.matrix(~ v2 + 0)))
#    v1a v1b v1c v2a v2b v2c
# 1    0   1   0   0   0   1
# 2    1   0   0   1   0   0
# 3    0   0   1   0   0   1
# 4    0   1   0   1   0   0
# 5    0   0   1   0   0   1
# 6    0   0   1   0   1   0
# 7    1   0   0   1   0   0
# 8    1   0   0   0   1   0
# 9    1   0   0   0   0   1
# 10   1   0   0   0   1   0
```

---

Note: Your output is just:

```
with(df, model.matrix(~ v2 + 0))
```

---

Note 2: This gives a `matrix`. Fairly obvious, but still, wrap it with `as.data.frame(.)` if you want a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 9):

There is a function in caret's package that does what you require, dummyVars. 
Here is the example of it's usage taken from the authors documentation:
http://topepo.github.io/caret/preprocess.html

```
library(earth)
data(etitanic)

dummies <- caret::dummyVars(survived ~ ., data = etitanic)
head(predict(dummies, newdata = etitanic))

  pclass.1st pclass.2nd pclass.3rd sex.female sex.male     age sibsp parch
1          1          0          0          1        0 29.0000     0     0
2          1          0          0          0        1  0.9167     1     2
3          1          0          0          1        0  2.0000     1     2
4          1          0          0          0        1 30.0000     1     2
5          1          0          0          1        0 25.0000     1     2
6          1          0          0          0        1 48.0000     0     0
```

The model.matrix options could be useful in case you had sparse data and wanted to use `Matrix::sparse.model.matrix`

Answer (score 4):

Just seen a closed question directed to here, and nobody has mentioned using the `dummies` package yet:

You can recode your variables using the `dummy.data.frame()` function which is built on top of `model.matrix()` but has easier syntax, some good options and will return a dataframe:

```
> dummy.data.frame(df, sep="_")
   v1_a v1_b v1_c v2_a v2_b v2_c
1     0    1    0    0    0    1
2     1    0    0    1    0    0
3     0    0    1    0    0    1
4     0    1    0    1    0    0
5     0    0    1    0    0    1
6     0    0    1    0    1    0
7     1    0    0    1    0    0
8     1    0    0    0    1    0
9     1    0    0    0    0    1
10    1    0    0    0    1    0
```

Some nice aspects of this function is you can easily specify delimeter for the new names (`sep=`), omit non-encoded variables (`all=F`) and comes with its own option `dummy.classes` that allows you to specify which classes of column should be encoded.

You can also just use the `dummy()` function to apply this to just one column.

Answer (score 3):

A fairly direct approach is to just use `table` on each column, tabulating the values in the column by the number of rows in the `data.frame`:

```
allLevels <- levels(factor(unlist(df)))
do.call(cbind, 
        lapply(df, function(x) table(sequence(nrow(df)), 
                                     factor(x, levels = allLevels))))
#    a b c a b c
# 1  0 1 0 0 0 1
# 2  1 0 0 1 0 0
# 3  0 0 1 0 0 1
# 4  0 1 0 1 0 0
# 5  0 0 1 0 0 1
# 6  0 0 1 0 1 0
# 7  1 0 0 1 0 0
# 8  1 0 0 0 1 0
# 9  1 0 0 0 0 1
# 10 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

I've used `factor` on "x" to make sure that even in cases where there are, say, no "c" values in a column, there will still be a "c" column in the output, filled with zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across another way. I noticed that when you run any of the contrasts functions with `contrasts` set to `FALSE`, it gives you one hot encoding. For example, `contr.sum(5, contrasts = FALSE)` gives

```
  1 2 3 4 5
1 1 0 0 0 0
2 0 1 0 0 0
3 0 0 1 0 0
4 0 0 0 1 0
5 0 0 0 0 1
```

To get this behavior for all of your factors, you can create a new contrast function and set it as the default. For example,

```
contr.onehot = function (n, contrasts, sparse = FALSE) {
  contr.sum(n = n, contrasts = FALSE, sparse = sparse)
}

options(contrasts = c("contr.onehot", "contr.onehot"))
model.matrix(~ . - 1, data = df)
```

This results in

```
   v1a v1b v1c v2a v2b v2c
1    0   0   1   0   0   1
2    0   1   0   1   0   0
3    0   0   1   0   1   0
4    1   0   0   0   1   0
5    0   1   0   0   1   0
6    0   1   0   0   0   1
7    1   0   0   0   1   0
8    0   1   0   0   1   0
9    0   1   0   1   0   0
10   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for more general case, when the amount of letters is not specified apriori:

```
convertABC <- function(x) {

    hold <- rep(0,max(match(as.matrix(df),letters))) # pre-format output

    codify <- function(x) {                          # define function for single char

        output <- hold                               # take empty vector
        output[match(x,letters)] <- 1                # place 1 according to letter pos
        return(output)
    }

    to.return <- t(sapply(as.character(x),codify))   # apply it to whole vector
    rownames(to.return) <- 1:nrow(to.return)         # nice rownames
    colnames(to.return) <- do.call(c,list(letters[1:max(match(as.matrix(df),letters))])) # nice columnnames
    return(to.return)
}
```

This function takes a vector of characters, and recodes it into binary values. To process all variables in `df`:

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(df,convertABC))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(correlationfunnel)
library(dplyr)
v1 = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE)
v2 = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE)
df = data.frame(v1,v2)
df

   v1 v2
1   b  c
2   c  c
3   c  a
4   c  c
5   a  a
6   b  b
7   b  c
8   b  c
9   c  a
10  b  c

df$id= 1:nrow(df)
df %>%
   select(-id) %>%
   binarize()

# A tibble: 10 x 6
   v1__a v1__b v1__c v2__a v2__b v2__c
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     1     0     0     0     1
 2     0     0     1     0     0     1
 3     0     0     1     1     0     0
 4     0     0     1     0     0     1
 5     1     0     0     1     0     0
 6     0     1     0     0     1     0
 7     0     1     0     0     0     1
 8     0     1     0     0     0     1
 9     0     0     1     1     0     0
10     0     1     0     0     0     1
```