# r combine factor levels from multiple data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

How to combine factor levels from two empty data.frames?

I have a big data set splitted into separate files. I need a data.frame that will have all possible levels for factor columns, but I can't load all parts at once, only part by part.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
data_structure = NULL
for (chunk_i in chunks){
    # load chunk_i data

    if(is.null(data_structure)){
        data_structure = data_i
    } else {
        # at this line factor levels will NOT be combined as I expect
        # but instead factor levels from 'data' will be stored to 'data_structure'
        data_structure = rbind(data_structure, data)
    }
    rm(data)

    # empty data frame, since I can't keep all data in memory
    # I want to keep only metadata, like factor levels
    data_structure = data_structure[0, ]
}
```

And this data_structure is needed to later [convert factors to binary columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200241/recode-categorical-factor-with-n-categories-into-n-binary-columns) like this:

```
result_i = model.matrix(~ . + 0, data=data_i, contrasts.arg = 
              lapply(data_structure, contrasts, contrasts=FALSE))
```

If factor levels a gathered from all parts of data then I can be sure that result_i will have exactly same binary columns as all other parts of data, even if in this particular case data_i have less factor levels in some columns.

**UPDATE**

Right now I use this solution:

```
all_levels = list()
for_each_chunk(function(data) {
    data_levels = Filter(Negate(is.null), sapply(data, levels))
    factor_names = unique(c(names(all_levels), names(data_levels)))
    lapply(factor_names, FUN=function(name){ 
        all_levels[[name]] <<- unique(c(all_levels[[name]], data_levels[[name]]))
    })
})
```

Not so elegant as for me, but haven't found nothing better yet.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a very silly solution that I am proposing. Why don't you do a stratified sample of each an every chunk and then read those chunks into a single dataframe. This way I think all the levels will be stored in metadata. You can do a stratified sample using the `sampling` package in R, or you can use this function that I had picked up from GIT hub sometime back:

```
stratified <- function(df, group, size, select = NULL, 
                       replace = FALSE, bothSets = FALSE) {
  if (is.null(select)) {
    df <- df
  } else {
    if (is.null(names(select))) stop("'select' must be a named list")
    if (!all(names(select) %in% names(df)))
      stop("Please verify your 'select' argument")
    temp <- sapply(names(select),
                   function(x) df[[x]] %in% select[[x]])
    df <- df[rowSums(temp) == length(select), ]
  }
  df.interaction <- interaction(df[group], drop = TRUE)
  df.table <- table(df.interaction)
  df.split <- split(df, df.interaction)
  if (length(size) > 1) {
    if (length(size) != length(df.split))
      stop("Number of groups is ", length(df.split),
           " but number of sizes supplied is ", length(size))
    if (is.null(names(size))) {
      n <- setNames(size, names(df.split))
      message(sQuote("size"), " vector entered as:\n\nsize = structure(c(",
              paste(n, collapse = ", "), "),\n.Names = c(",
              paste(shQuote(names(n)), collapse = ", "), ")) \n\n")
    } else {
      ifelse(all(names(size) %in% names(df.split)),
             n <- size[names(df.split)],
             stop("Named vector supplied with names ",
                  paste(names(size), collapse = ", "),
                  "\n but the names for the group levels are ",
                  paste(names(df.split), collapse = ", ")))
    }
  } else if (size < 1) {
    n <- round(df.table * size, digits = 0)
  } else if (size >= 1) {
    if (all(df.table >= size) || isTRUE(replace)) {
      n <- setNames(rep(size, length.out = length(df.split)),
                    names(df.split))
    } else {
      message(
        "Some groups\n---",
        paste(names(df.table[df.table < size]), collapse = ", "),
        "---\ncontain fewer observations",
        " than desired number of samples.\n",
        "All observations have been returned from those groups.")
      n <- c(sapply(df.table[df.table >= size], function(x) x = size),
             df.table[df.table < size])
    }
  }
  temp <- lapply(
    names(df.split),
    function(x) df.split[[x]][sample(df.table[x],
                                     n[x], replace = replace), ])
  set1 <- do.call("rbind", temp)

  if (isTRUE(bothSets)) {
    set2 <- df[!rownames(df) %in% rownames(set1), ]
    list(SET1 = set1, SET2 = set2)
  } else {
    set1
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the source of your `stratified` function.

Comment: Hi, it looks a bit too complicated.

Comment: Hi, it is not as complicated as it looks. Just copy this function and run it, you will able to access it like any other function in R-Studio, and it will sample the chunks for you. And as Pascal pointed out, I have located where I found this function: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112