# How can I reshape my data.table efficiently

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have a data.table `DT`

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c(1,2,3),each=4), y=c("A","B"), v=sample(1:100,12))
DT
    x y   v
 1: 1 A  29
 2: 1 B  92
 3: 1 A 100
 4: 1 B  82
 5: 2 A  28
 6: 2 B  26
 7: 2 A  18
 8: 2 B  22
 9: 3 A  30
10: 3 B  96
11: 3 A  15
12: 3 B   4
```

I would like to expand it like bellow, creating a new column for each value of `x` and reporting the `v` values, no structure in the data should be expected (not by blocks like bellow)

```
    x y v.1  v.2 v.3
 1: 1 A  29   NA  NA
 2: 1 B  92   NA  NA
 3: 1 A 100   NA  NA
 4: 1 B  82   NA  NA
 5: 2 A  NA   28  NA
 6: 2 B  NA   26  NA
 7: 2 A  NA   18  NA
 8: 2 B  NA   22  NA
 9: 3 A  NA   NA  30
10: 3 B  NA   NA  96
11: 3 A  NA   NA  15
12: 3 B  NA   NA   4
```

I asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187293/a-reshape-puzzle-in-data-table) but cannot adapt the answer G Grothendieck gave us at the time...

EDIT:
As usual I just almost got it after I wrote the post... I just need to replace those 0 by NA (I might get 0 in v and I want to be able to dissociate v==0 from missing items)

```
DT2 <- DT[, {SUM.<-factor(x); data.table(model.matrix(~ SUM.:v + 0))}]
txtR) DT2
    SUM.1:v SUM.2:v SUM.3:v
 1:      29       0       0
 2:      92       0       0
 3:     100       0       0
 4:      82       0       0
 5:       0      28       0
 6:       0      26       0
 7:       0      18       0
 8:       0      22       0
 9:       0       0      30
10:       0       0      96
11:       0       0      15
12:       0       0       4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c(1,2,3),each=4), y=c("A","B"), v=sample(1:100,12))
```

This gives

```
    x y  v
 1: 1 A 27
 2: 1 B 37
 3: 1 A 57
 4: 1 B 89
 5: 2 A 20
 6: 2 B 86
 7: 2 A 97
 8: 2 B 62
 9: 3 A 58
10: 3 B  6
11: 3 A 19
12: 3 B 16
```

Next, the answer:

```
ux <- unique(DT$x)
DT[,c(v.=lapply(ux,function(i)v[x==i])),by="x,y"]
```

which gives

```
    x y v.1 v.2 v.3
 1: 1 A  27  NA  NA
 2: 1 A  57  NA  NA
 3: 1 B  37  NA  NA
 4: 1 B  89  NA  NA
 5: 2 A  NA  20  NA
 6: 2 A  NA  97  NA
 7: 2 B  NA  86  NA
 8: 2 B  NA  62  NA
 9: 3 A  NA  NA  58
10: 3 A  NA  NA  19
11: 3 B  NA  NA   6
12: 3 B  NA  NA  16
```

That answer might break in later versions of R, but the OP pointed out that this works too and may be faster:

```
DT[,paste0("v.",ux):=lapply(ux,function(i)v[x==i]),by="x"]
```

Comment: I think it's sufficient for `by=x`?

Comment: Hmm, the desired output has a "y" column anyway. Without putting it in the `by`, would I have to do something like a merge or `DT[,c(list(y=y),v.=lapply(1:3,function(i)v[x==i])),by="x"]`?

Comment: @Frank, I think so. Your current answer with `by="x,y"` won't be identical to OP's requirement. Look carefully at the values you get for your columns and compare with mine.. (except the NA, which I still don't know how to replace while creating model.matrix).

Comment: @statquant Okay, you're right. I've changed it to go over all x values.

Comment: @Arun I still don't see it. Yours has a "v" column; 0s instead of `NA`s; and rows in a different order, but otherwise, they look the same to me... By the way, I didn't read in the OP's data, but re-ran the generating code with a seed.

Comment: `DT[,paste0("v.",ux):=lapply(ux,function(i)v[x==i]),by="x"]` works better (and is probably quicker too)

Comment: I'm not seeing warnings with ... R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26); Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit); data.table_1.8.6

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30139/discussion-between-frank-and-statquant)

Comment: @statquant, yes I get the warning too on R 3.0.0

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
tt <- model.matrix(data=DT, ~ factor(x):rep(1, nrow(DT)) + 0)
tt[tt==0] <- NA
cbind(DT, DT$v * tt)
#     x y   v factor(x)1:v factor(x)2:v factor(x)3:v
#  1: 1 A  69           69           NA           NA
#  2: 1 B  39           39           NA           NA
#  3: 1 A  76           76           NA           NA
#  4: 1 B  49           49           NA           NA
#  5: 2 A 100           NA          100           NA
#  6: 2 B  95           NA           95           NA
#  7: 2 A  36           NA           36           NA
#  8: 2 B  73           NA           73           NA
#  9: 3 A  86           NA           NA           86
# 10: 3 B  20           NA           NA           20
# 11: 3 A  59           NA           NA           59
# 12: 3 B  12           NA           NA           12
```

Comment: do you see a trick to replace those 0s by NA it's too bad cause it's lightnin' quick...

Comment: @statquant, not straightforward, but I've managed.. check the edit please.

Comment: @statquant, You mean efficient in terms of runtime or lines of code (or both)?

Answer (score 3):

You *could* simply loop over the `x`'s and use `data.table` assignment:

```
setkey(DT, x)
for (i in unique(DT$x)) {
  DT[J(i), paste0("v.", i) := v]
}
```

P.S. I really wish the following worked, but `.GRP` is not available there:

```
DT[, paste0("v.", .GRP) := v, by = x]
```

**edit** one more solution (trying to get the above `.GRP` idea to work somehow), using `rbind.fill` (I didn't run very careful benches, but this seemed to scale quite well)

```
library(plyr)

cbind(DT,
      rbind.fill(DT[, list(list(setnames(data.table(v), paste0("v.", .GRP)))),
                      by = x]$V1))
```

Comment: +1. Re: the second idea, that sounds like a good feature request, eh?

Comment: If the feature enabling `DT[, paste0("v.", .GRP) := v, by = x]` were requested it would be nice if it included a facility to specify the fill value in case some other value than `NA` were desired.

Comment: @Frank, I second this. But I think this has been raised sometime before.. iirc. And I think this would be the fastest by far, especially as the columns are already allocated in data.table..